# Android. How to disable text wrap by characters and enable only by words?

Tags: android, textview

How to enable text wrap only by words in auto-sized AppCompatTextView?

Answer (score 1):

you can try the combinations of [android:lineBreakWordStyle](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView#attr_android:lineBreakWordStyle) and [android:lineBreakStyle](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView#attr_android:lineBreakStyle)

Comment: "Unknown attribute android:lineBreakWordStyle"

Comment: maybe it's only in API 33